# What powers are shown on the Swamp Thing TV show?

Tags: dc, swamp-thing-the-series

According to his [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swamp_Thing#Powers_and_abilities) page, Swamp Thing's powers consist of:

- Inhabiting and animating vegetable matter
- **Regrowing his own body parts**
- Transferring his consciousness
- Growing exponentially in size
- Superhuman strength
- **Controlling plant life**
- Mastery of the Fire, Earth, Water, and **Air** elements

But from the show I've seen him:

- Resurrect the (freshly) dead
- Cure illness directly (not by manipulating surrounding plants) using either magic or his own blood
- Cause hallucinations
- Shrink others down to figurine size (don't believe this was a hallucination)
- Talk to the dead

The bolded items in the first list (self-healing, controlling plants and air) are the only ones that I've seen happen on the show. He is pretty strong, but so far nothing close to *superhuman*.

**What are all the abilities that Swamp Thing demonstrates in the TV show?**

Comment: Is this a new series?

Comment: @Adamant: No. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swamp_Thing:_The_Series

Comment: @Adamant I'm old school